# A problem involving random variables and sigma- algebras generated by them

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to show that if $T$ is an uncountable set and $(X_t)_{t \in T}$ a process, then

$$\sigma(X_t : t \in T) = \bigcup_{\Gamma \subset T,\ \Gamma\text{ countable}} \sigma(X_t : t \in \Gamma).$$

The $``\supset"$ inclusion is evident.

For $``\subset"$, showing that the right side is $\sigma$-algebra is easy, but then...?

Thank you!

Comment: You really need to work on your understanding of TeX-style mathematical notation markup.  Look at my edits. I deleted your \hspace and set that line as displayed rather than inline; then I got rid of your \underset, since with things like \sum and \bigcup that automatically happens in displayed rather than inline settings.  But in an inline setting, using \limits rather than \underset is the standard, and simpler, way to do that, and in some contexts it is needed to get proper spacing between characters.  Also notice the use of \text{}. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

The definition of $\sigma(X_t:t\in T)$ is that its the smallest sigma algebra...

Comment: that contains all $\{X_t \in B\}$ for all $B$ and $t \in T$

Comment: Does the right side contain all the sets $\{X_t \in B\}$ forall $t \in T$ ?